# Is the /t/ sound in "stopped" not pronounced in "we stopped for petrol"?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, connected-speech

I'm wondering if all /t/ sounds which are at the end of a word are often omitted in British English when it is followed by a consonant when you are speaking normally fast?

As I've noticed that it seemingly occurs so frequently; such as "we stopp*ed* for petrol", "bes*t*-seller", "the tes*t* migh*t* be cancelled", "the las*t* knight", "it's har*d* cheating", "I don'*t* lie" and so.

And I'm particularly not sure about this one: "the test is over". Is this "the tesisover" or "the tes-tisover", when you speak as usual?

Comment: There isn't a cast-iron convention as such in British English: whether the sound is pronounced or not depends almost entirely on the region and accent of the person speaking.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, so is it common in either way?

Comment: It's pretty common to "cut off" a T sound where I'm from (northeast of Scotland) but as a general rule I don't think many British accents throttle it. I know a lot of English accents where the T sound is actually *more* pronounced.

Comment: Yes, I know there are accents and dialects aplenty. Do you, as a British, find it hard or maybe annoying to listen to a person who often drops or throttles the /t/?

Comment: Not at all, I do it all the time. :)

Comment: So does my teacher, and I prefer speaking that way too. Now I can ensure my own accent is fine. Thank you

Comment: Ah, and the last question, please?

Comment: JavaLatte's answered that one pretty nicely. :)

Comment: Sorry for this extra question. Should I do it in formal contexts, in presentation for instance. I'm an MC for an annual event at university, and there will be several British invitees, but I don't know exactly where they come from, nor their own accents.

Comment: The best rule of thumb I can suggest to you is to enunciate as clearly as possible when you're presenting events and things. I used to be a caller in a bingo club and enunciated every syllable of what I was saying, because it was not worth my life if a little old lady misheard me calling her numbers. :P

Comment: I'm sorry but I couldn't understand your point in distinction. Did you mean I should never drop or throttle any syllable, or I could do it but I must be certain that everyone will hear the sound clearly?

Comment: In formal settings I would try to avoid throttling syllables when possible because some people have a hard time hearing clearly when you do that. That's obviously just my opinion, though, please don't take it as gospel.

Answer (score 1):

This arises when a final consonant is followed by word beginning with an alveolar consonant, for example a "d". Forgive my failure to use phonetic writing, I don't have a phonetic keyboard handy, but here are some examples:

> "he's stopped" is pronounced "hisstopt"

the d changes to t because the preceding consonant is unvoiced

> "he's stopped doing it" is pronounced "hisstop?doingit"

where the ? is a gluttal stop.

To answer the final part of your question, in informal spoken English, "test is" would be contracted to "test's" before any other thanges occur, so your sentence would go

> "the test is over" pronounced as "thetestsover".

Comment: Is "thetestsover" pronounced as "thetes|sover"? ("|" is a flash pause).

Comment: @gnouvl: maybe after a few gin & tonics or when spoken quickly. I am willing to carry out tests on the former situation if required. In these two situations, the voicing of the o moves back to the preceding s  and the t disappears, giving "theTessSover". The start of voicing creates a discontinuity but i don't think there is a pause, flash or otherwise.

Comment: If you speak clearly and at a reasonable speed, you will only drop the consonants that are physically difficult to say. These are the ones that even BBC newsreaders drop. If you attempt to keep the difficult consinants, you will have to add a "schwa" -an a-sound- between the words, for example " I don'taknow" and then you will sound like a non-native speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the issues of accent that others have mentioned, it depends very much on how carefully one is speaking.

If I want to emphasise "stopped" for some reason, or if I am speaking very clearly (say, over a noisy phone connection), I will clearly pronounce the /t/.
Normally, during the "stop" (vocal closure) of the /p/ my tongue will move to pronounce the /t/, but the consonant (cluster) will not be released, and my lips will move to form the /f/ and release the sound in that fricative. The /t/ sound is just barely audible as a transition between the /p/ and the /f/, so the cluster is /ptf/, but with only the final /f/ being released. In rapid speech, my tongue won't even get that far, and the cluster will be /pf/.

Comment: Yes, that's just exactly the point what I've always been confused at. Thank you